# Fixed points cohomology via Lannes T-functor

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Is there any reference to the proof of following: let $T$ denote the [Lannes functor.](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Lannes-T-functor) Then (see the link above for more details) for any finite $E$-complex $X$ (where $E$ is finite-dimensional $\mathbb F_p$-vector space), one should have $T_EH_E^*(X) = H^*BE \otimes H^*(X^E)$?

Wilkerson and Dwyer (”Smith theory and the functor T”, p. 2) give a reference to the unpublished manuscript “Cohomology of groups and function spaces” by Lannes. But I can not find it anywhere.

Comment: Generally speaking, questions should be as self-contained as possible, so it would be better to give at least a hint of the notation than to defer entirely to an external article.

Comment: @LSpice, I have added some details.

Comment: @LSpice, and even more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with your assertion, which, when $X$ is specialized to a point, says that $$T_EH^*(BE) = H^*(BE).$$  But this is **not** true.  (I can't access the Dywer-Wilkerson paper you mention right at the moment.)

Lannes' famous 1992 paper in Pub. IHES (en francais!) has a functor he calls $Fix$, and $Fix(H_E^*(X)) \simeq H^*(X^E)$ for $X$ a finite $E$--complex. $Fix$ is a variant of $T_E$.  Maybe this will help you.